# Recruiter Contacts me for a new job

Tags: interviewing, new-job, probation

I had a very good impression on this recruiter, at the end of 2017.

She strived so that I would be hired with a salary above my expectations etc.

I didn't know I was going to work with the worst infamous boss ever, a boss who keeps losing subordinates. Everyone agrees she doesn't have the skills for filling that position.

This boss affirms, implicitly and explicitly, that she won't hire me at the end of my extended probation.

Has this recruiter heard something and took the initiative to propose a new job for me one month before getting fired?

Comment: How do you expect that recruiter to save you? It is unclear what you are asking, mind rephrasing it?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you are asking.  Are you asking if the recruiter knows about the terrible boss and will have a new job for you?

Comment: @TheRealLester yes, it seems that is what is being asked here

Comment: I am asking if the recruiter heard that my boss might not hire me, through someone from HR department maybe to find a solution (personality mismatch with boss, my technical skills are not in question).

Comment: vtc i have no idea. nobody does. this isn't an answerable question. more to the point, why does *OP* care? OP already knows the job is going away in a month...

Comment: unless your recruiter happens to be on here, the only way to know would be to look in her brain.

Comment: Did the recruiter send you details about a job or did they just ask how it's going? Did they address you by name or did they just send a generic email that they could've just sent to everyone on their system?

Comment: They contacted me by phone for a job in a different company, after having visited my linkedin profile. They went through many questions (how is your level in English? would you be willing to travel abroad occasionally? etc).

Comment: Often companies have conditions in the recruiters contract that "guarantee" that their candidates can do the job (limited by X months). Most likely your current company already informed the recruiter that you are not a good fit and are contesting the commission the recruiter gets for placing you there. Most likely this recruiter is protecting THEIR salary by working to get you another job.

Answer (score 3):

> Has this recruiter heard something and took the initiative to propose a new job for me before getting fired?

There is no possible way we can know this.

However, it is still **highly unlikely** that this recruiter somehow happened to hear about your specific situation, and even more unlikely that he will start searching for a job offer for you without you asking or to "save you".

If you fear you will not be given the permanent position, I suggest **you start job-hunting ASAP** (perhaps contact this recruiter yourself), so you don't end up without a job.

Comment: @bharal well you have a point, but if OP is counting on the recruiter to save him then this will come as unexpected. It's better to take a more active role on this matter (editing the answer to remove that unnecessary word)

Comment: Some said it's a trap: "the recruiter is acting with the blessing of your boss and the company’s HR department, which means they want to get rid of you".

Comment: My job is not over yet. my boss keeps alluding ... but has taken no action yet.

Comment: @user Unless you actually enjoy the suspense of being constantly told you'll be fired "soon" and waiting to see if it will really happen, I suggest you take that allusion as truth and plan accordingly - ie: start looking for a new job.

Comment: Some colleages, who had been there for years, warned me a couple of months ago, but due to some resignations and my boss's dark collaboration history, these colleagues have been telling me that I am safe ...